# FloatingActionButtonMenu

Tags: android, mobile

Utilizei um material do Clans que esta neste link https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton2
por sinal muito bom.

Mas  estou com dificuldade de aplicar animação neste *floating*.
Gostaria de reproduzir a mesma animação que faz no Mapa do Google maps, quando tocar na tela ele se esconder. O floating e a barra de pesquisa, mas ja tentei de tudo e li um monte de tutorial, mas nao consegui fazer, se alguem tiver alguma ideia.
Estou utilizando a versão mais atual do Android Studio e a API do Google.

Comment: se voce está utilizando a versão mais atual do android studio, basta que na hora em que for criar seu projeto voce escolha a opção "Basic Activity" no terceiro "next" que vc aplicar, ai já tem uma activity com actionbuttom mais facil de se manipular

Comment: eu fiz assim, mas queria utilizar um menu de floating, por isso que utilizei o do clans, mas nao estou conseguindo o evento de quando clicar na tela ele esconder.

Comment: O link está quebrado.

Comment: este é o link correto https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Comment: opa, mas dá pra fazer o que tu quer e mais ainda com nativo, veja: https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html, bem legal esse aqui ó

Comment: vou testar e volto a postar aqui obrigado por enquanto.